# Sublime Text 3: Duplicates Autocompletion

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use various plugins for autocompletion (All Autocomplete, CodeIntel and more) and actually, I want to keep all of them. But sometimes, I have duplicates in my list of completion which is kind of annoying. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to modify the `sublime_plugin.py` file in your ST installation folder, then this is possible.

These instructions are valid for build 3125/3126, but be aware that you will lose your changes and need to re-apply them (if relevant) when you upgrade ST when a new build is released.

1. Open the folder where ST is installed
2. Open `sublime_plugin.py`
3. Find `def on_query_completions`
4. Replace `return (completions, flags)` with `return (list(set(completions)), flags)`"
5. Save the file
6. Restart ST

You may need to use a more advanced solution to remove duplicates if your plugins are suggesting multiple completions with the same trigger.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this also in a new plugin? I would write one if it's technically possible.

Comment: I think you should be able to monkey patch it. Just `import sublime_plugin` then replace the method with your own `sublime_plugin.on_query_completions = `...